# Why does the background of my folder not change?

Tags: windows-7, directory, ini

Finding an interesting concept in this [blogpost](http://www.tweakandtrick.com/2013/08/folder-background.html)
I saved this file as desktop.ini in a folder:

[image: Default image from Win7]

Nothing happens when I open the folder.

What should I change about the code I have in my desktop.ini to achieve the desired results?

Comment: Try removing the braces around the image path (and try adding double quotes, since you have spaces in the path).

Comment: Afraid that didnt change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a mistake on my part. I did not mention that in Windows 7 and higher versions of Windows, [{BE098140-A513-11D0-A3A4-00C04FD706EC}] should be [AveFolder] and you need to install [this app](http://sites.google.com/site/tweakandtrickblog/AveFolderBg.zip). So, your code would be something like:-

```
[AveFolder]
iconarea_image="location of the image"
iconarea_text=0x00ffffff
```

Comment: Afraid that is still not working for me

Comment: To install the app, make sure you run install.bat as an Administrator by right clicking on it.